# How to use search item in the toolbar?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I have an macOS app using Xcode 11 for development and I have an   @IBOutlet weak var searchTextField: NSSearchField! in my view controller class to filter a table view. Also, I have menu options for this search field. This code works fine. However, I would like to move this search function to the toolbar. So, I added a search toolbar item to the toolbar and CTRL-Draged it to the first responder and connected it to an @IBAction func. But I am at a loss of how to proceed. What are the steps required implement a search feature in the toolbar.  Please advise.

Comment: Is the action of the search field in the view controller connected to an action of this view controller? To which action is the search field in the toolbar connected?

Comment: The search field that is in the view controller code is : IBOutlet weak var searchTextField: NSSearchField!". All the working code is using this field. The action for the toolbar search field action is    IBAction func searchCustomer(_ obj: NSSearchField) {
        print("Search Selected") .. When I said first responder I meant first responder of the IB.

Comment: Which class implements `searchCustomer`? Do you use the outlet outside the `NSSearchFieldDelegate` and search field action methods?

Comment: Is the view controller the content view controller of the window?

Comment: Yes, the view controller is the content view controller for the window and it is in this class where I have the IBAction searchCustomer.

Comment: Is `searchCustomer` called?

Comment: Yes searchCustomer is called when I click in the NSSearchField in the toolbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this from another user. It is exactly what I was looking for.

```
//  ViewController.swift
// This assumes the search field is first in the toolbar
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    override func viewWillAppear() {
        
        guard let toolbar = self.view.window?.toolbar else {
            return
        }
                
        guard let searchFieldToolbarItem = toolbar.items.first else {
            return
        }

        guard let searchField = searchFieldToolbarItem.view as? NSSearchField else {
            return
        }
                
        searchField.target = self
        searchField.action = #selector (procSearchFieldInput (sender:))
    }
    
    @objc func procSearchFieldInput (sender:NSSearchField) {
        print ("\(#function): \(sender.stringValue)")
    }
}
```